# Using dplyr mutate to find position of character in string

Tags: regex, r, string, dataframe, dplyr

I have data frame with a column of strings, that of an number id followed by "-" and then a month year. I am trying to parse the string to get the month and year. As a very first step, I used dplyr::mutate() and

```
regexpr()
regexpr("-",yearid)[1]
```

to create a new column that shows the position of this "-" character. But seems like regexpr() performs very differently inside a mutate(), than when used separately. It does not seem to update depending on the string, but carries over the string position from previous rows. In the example below I expect the position of "-" character to be 4,4, and 5 in the respective yearid. But I get 4,4, and 4 - so this 4 is not correct. When I run regexpr separately I dont see this issue.

Wondering if I am missing something, and how can I get position of "-" dynamically that is specific for each value of yearid? May be there is an easier way to get January, and 1997.

```
yearid <- c("50 - January 1995","51 - January 1996","100 - January 1997")
data.df <- data.frame(yearid)
data.df <- mutate(data.df, trimpos = regexpr("-",str_trim(yearid))[1],
              pos = regexpr("-",yearid)[1])

> data.df
                yearid test1 test2
 1  50 - January 1995     4     4
 2  51 - January 1996     4     4
 3 100 - January 1997     4     4
```

On the other hand using regexpr as such I get the output as expected:

```
> regexpr("-",yearid[1])[1]
[1] 4
> regexpr("-",yearid[2])[1]
[1] 4
> regexpr("-",yearid[3])[1]
[1] 5
```

Finally, I have my sessionInfo() below

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] stringr_1.0.0    dplyr_0.4.1      readr_0.2.2.9000

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] assertthat_0.1       DBI_0.3.1            knitr_1.10.5               lazyeval_0.1.10.9000 magrittr_1.5         parallel_3.1.1      
[7] Rcpp_0.11.6          stringi_0.4-1        tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: Just drop the `[1]`s from your `mutate` expression.

Comment: Pretty pointless to use dplyr when there is no grouping and `regexpr()` is vectorized.

Comment: @nrussell Thanks - if it may help, any idea [1] from the regexpr were the ones that caused the issue that I notice? Just wanted to ensure I got the underlying issue too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `regexpr` function from the `stringr` library returns a vector of positions with two additional attributes attached `match.length` and `useBytes`. As mentioned in the comments, this vector can be assigned directly to the data frame. This can be done using the `mutate` function or without.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

id_month_year <- c(
    "50 - January 1995",
    "51 - January 1996",
    "100 - January 1997"
)
data <- data.frame(id_month_year, another_column = 1)

## create new column using mutate
data <- data %>% mutate(pos1 = regexpr("-", data$id_month_year))

## create new column without mutate
data$pos2 <- regexpr("-", data$id_month_year)

print(data)
```

Here are the new columns:

```
       id_month_year another_column pos1 pos2
1  50 - January 1995              1    4    4
2  51 - January 1996              1    4    4
3 100 - January 1997              1    5    5
```

I would suggest using the `separate` function from the `tidyr` library. Here's an example code snippet:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

id_month_year <- c(
    "50 - January 1995",
    "51 - January 1996",
    "100 - January 1997"
)
data <- tbl_df(data.frame(id_month_year, another_column = 1))

clean <- data %>%
    separate(
        id_month_year,
        into = c("id", "month", "year"),
        sep = "[- ]+",
        convert = TRUE
    )

print(clean)
```

And here's the resulting clean data frame:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 4]

     id   month  year another_column
  (int)   (chr) (int)          (dbl)
1    50 January  1995              1
2    51 January  1996              1
3   100 January  1997              1
```